# Как загрузить N строку из файла в переменную?

Tags: vb.net

Скажите пожалуйста как загрузить N строку из файла в переменную?

Comment: оптимально - мапишь файл в память, и в памяти разбираешь построчно.

Comment: алгоритм:

 1. заводишь счётчик (например X)
 2. считываешь по 1символу и проверяешь
    равен ли считанный символ, символу
    новой строки, если да то X=X+1
 3. выходим когда X= (номер строки)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На C#:

```
var line = File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(N).First();
```

Переведёте на VB сами?

---

Дополнение: если вам надо таким образом прочитать *много* строк, воспользуйтесь просто `File.ReadLines(filename)`, которая выдаст (ленивый) список всех строк файла. С ним можно работать стандартными функциями LINQ-to-objects: `Skip`, `Take`, `Select`, `Where` и т. п.

Comment: Мне кажется, или можно просто сделать так: 


    File.ReadLines(filename)(N)

Не могу проверить, т. к. нету Windows под рукой XD

Comment: @Niki-Timofe: не совсем. Функция [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) возвращает `IEnumerable<string>`, его нельзя проиндексировать. Функция, для которой это работало бы -- [`ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), которая возвращает `string[]`. Недостаток функции `ReadAllLines` -- то, что она читает _весь_ файл в память (иначе как же данные попадут в массив?), в то время как `ReadLines` читает строки только при необходимости, в нашем случае -- только первые `N` строк, и не помещает ненужные результаты в память.